# subclasses of Parse.Object with save function

Tags: parsing

I subclassd the Parse.Object like below:

```
    var CFSScoreData = Parse.Object.extend("CFSScoreData",
{
    initialize:function () {
        this.playerName = "RACCOON";
        this.playTimeInSec = 0;
        this.rank = 0;
            this.updateScore();
    },
    updateScore:function () {
        this.set("playerName", this.playerName);
        this.set("playTimeInSec", this.playTimeInSec);
        this.set("rank", this.rank);
    },
    saveScore:function () {
        this.updateScore();
        this.save(null, {
              success: function() {
                  alert("saveSuccess");
              },
              error: function(error) {
                  alert("saveError");
              }
        });
    },
}
);
```

and this worked fine.

But I want to get the id of the object after saving so I tried:

```
saveScore:function () {
    this.updateScore();
    this.save(null, {
          success: function(this) {
              alert("saveSuccess" + this.id);
          },
          error: function(error) {
              alert("saveError");
          }
    });
},
```

But it did not work...

Any advice will appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Silly I am ~

It should be:

```
saveScore:function () {
    this.updateScore();
    this.save(null, {
          success: function(scoreData) {
              alert("saveSuccess" + scoreData.id);
          },
          error: function(error) {
              alert("saveError");
          }
    });
},
```